# Walnut Sapling Stem Getting Black

Tags: diseases, pests, rot, walnut

I am worried about this walnut sapling. It was replanted last month and look healthy, hewever, I noticed the lower part of the stem got black. I am worried that the sapling might die. What is causing this black color? Is it rotten? Is there something I can do to help it? Please note that he tree is currently dormant and is planted in a public space, between buildings, so the options to protect it are obviously limited.[image]